# Implement Autodesk forge database with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit, autodesk-forge

I've created an alexa app that is currently using dynamodb as my database however i'd like to use autodesk forge instead.

Can anyone give my guidance or provides links on how i can link AWS with forge?

Comment: Forge does not have a Database, I think you are going correctly with DynamoDB, What do you want to do on the Forge side?

Comment: Also you can check these 2 post we have of using AWS with Forge and there is one specific to DynamoDB. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/deploy-forge-net-apps-aws-elastic-beanstalk

DynamoDB one 

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-properties-viewer-net-lambda-dynamodb

Comment: @JaimeRosales Currently i have a semi working setup where i can ask alexa for different machine states at different dates and times. Currently i have to manually upload the data into dynamodb, but ive been told the data i need is stored on forge, i have no experience with forge so wanted to make my current setup work so i can pull and recall the data from forge. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @JaimeRosales sorry a friend of mine just clarified for me, we're using forge as a bridge between the database and aws, so its being used to connect to aws, any direction you can give on how i can do this?

Comment: check both of the blog post I mentioned above.